# javascript function does not work within jquery $(document).ready

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript">
    //Slider Function
    function projectrefinesearch() {
        alert('yes');
        var SliderSelectedMinPrice=$('#SliderSelectedMinPrice').val();
        alert(SliderSelectedMinPrice);
        var SliderSelectedMaxPrice=$('#SliderSelectedMaxPrice').val();


        if(SliderSelectedMinPrice!=''){
            postdata+='&minprice='+SliderSelectedMinPrice;
        }
        if(SliderSelectedMaxPrice!=''){
            postdata+='&maxprice='+SliderSelectedMaxPrice;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo SITEURL; ?>ajax.php',
            data:postdata,
            type:'POST',
            beforeSend:function() {
                $('#newloader').show();
            },
            success: function(output) {
                $('#newloader').hide();
                $('.left_content_part').html(output);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#priceslider #jslider-left').mouseup(function(){
            var val=$('#Sliderprice').val()
            var init=0;
            var a=val.split(";");
            init=a[0];
            //alert(init);
            document.getElementById("SliderSelectedMinPrice").value=init;
            projectrefinesearch();
        });
    }
</script>
```

its a price slider for budget (you can see it here http://www.indianpropertyoption.com/p/search-projects/result) after getting value in init, `document.getElementById("SliderSelectedMinPrice").value` and `projectrefinesearch();` is not working.
`document.getElementById("SliderSelectedMinPrice")` remains `null`. plz help me

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle for your code

Comment: please post the relevant HTML code in your question, as external links tend to go inactive quite frequently

Comment: 1. Fix the formatting in your question, your code is a nightmare to read (which often means people just don't bother). 2. That "HTML code" isn't HTML, it's just a `<script>` tag - post the HTML for the elements you're trying to work with. 3. Which script are we supposed to look at - the top one or the bottom one? Are they both on your page running at the same/different times?

Answer (score 0):

> keep javascript function outside of ready function like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var one =  $("#someid").val();
    var two =  $("#someid2").val();

    Hello(one,two);
});

function Hello(one,two){
  alert("I am here"+one);
}
```

Comment: there are some values in $(document).ready(function() which is to passed in hello function and then process hello.

Comment: you can pass many parameters like this also. code is updated and used many times